# Generic C# method ambiguous even though mutually exclusive constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, ambiguous

Why are these two methods considered ambiguous?

```
public static T Work<T>(this MyClass thing) where T : class { ... }
public static T? Work<T>(this MyClass thing) where T : struct { ... }
```

The constraints `class` and `struct` are mutually exclusive, are they not? So any call to this method should be unambiguous, for any type `T`, right? Because `T` can't both be a reference type AND a value type...?

Is this simply an oversight in the C# compiler/language def?

What I'm trying to do is create a generic method that will return `null` in some situations meaning "no value was present", and make this method able to handle both reference and value types. For value types `T` I would like the return type to be `Nullable<T>`, or shorter `T?`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think type restraints are considered when the compiler is comparing method signatures for ambiguity. I believe the only things that are checked are the method name and the number and type(s) of the parameters.

Comment: Return type is not considered when deciding whether method overloads are distinct or not.

Comment: @Abion47, so it would seem, but in that case I think this should be improved.

Comment: @Chris I know that and there are good reasons for that. But I think the constraint on `T` should be considered.

Comment: Whether it should be considered or not is not something we can answer. Post a bug in Microsoft's GitHub and ask for their opinion

Comment: Such a constraint would impose a LOT of extra work for the compiler, as it would have to consider every possible type that `T` could be and make sure that there isn't any overlap between the two methods.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think we can stop here. Thanks for the pointer to the duplicate, which I was unable to find before posting this. Understood: I'm not missing something, it's just the way it is. This is not the forum for opinions about it. Over and out.

Comment: You ask whether this was an *oversight*. It was not an *oversight*. "Oversight" implies that the C# design team failed to consider this factor and the design ended up this way by accident. That is not at all true. **This design was a deliberate choice**. Maybe you think that was a poor choice -- lots of people do! -- but it was a choice, not an oversight.

Comment: It doesn't work like this, but it works when you have a parameter of type `T` (in the method with the class constraint) and `T?` (in the method with hte struct constraint)

Comment: @Abion47: You are almost right. Method signature is: name, parameter arity, parameter types, parameter type out/ref-ness (out/ref/in are considered the same for purposes of signature checking), parameter type modifiers (rarely used in C#), and generic type parameter arity.  Not included in the signature: return type, generic constraints, attributes, formal parameter names, type parameter names.

Comment: @Dennis_E That's because `T?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<T>` which is a completely different type than `T`, which makes the parameter types of the two methods different and thus satisfies the different signature requirement.

Comment: @EricLippert Dang, I knew I was oversimplifying it.

Comment: @Abion47: Yeah, well, you didn't have to write the signature duplication error detection code; I did! :)

Comment: @KjellRilbe: If you want to see about a hundred people disagreeing with me that this choice was a good choice, see the comments to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/ (Unfortunately, Microsoft has removed the formatting which indicates which portions of the comments are my replies, which makes it a little confusing.)

Comment: @EricLippert "A little confusing", if you read 1 comment it's only a little :)

Comment: @KjellRilbe: To address your primary concern: Yes, it is irritatingly difficult to write a generic method in C# that returns null on failure for any type. Your best bet might be to return `default(T)`, which will be `null` for any reference or nullable value type, and the "zero" of any non-nullable value type. (That is, 0 for int, double, decimal, false for bool, and so on.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could return a `(bool, T)` tuple, where the bool indicates success or failure, and the `T` is the value.  Note that of course this is how `Nullable<T>` is actually implemented! It's a little unfortunate that in C# 2 the designers did not extend nullability marking to all types, rather than just value types.

Comment: @EricLippert Fully understood and respected, I'm not going to argue. Solved using two different method names.

Comment: @EricLippert, note that this was changed in c# 7.3 (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.3/improved-overload-candidates.md) **"When a method group contains some generic methods whose type arguments do not satisfy their constraints, these members are removed from the candidate set."**. Your example in the blog post now calls Foo(Animal), verified in LinqPad, and dating got easier :-)
(Doesn't affect the problem in this question)

Comment: @adrianm: Thanks for letting me know; I have not been keeping up with the small changes. That's disappointing frankly; I believe the initial design was the best one. I'll take a look at the design notes and see what argument convinced the design team.